# Intelligent cleaning up the Trash on GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, trash

Currently I see no solution to clean up `~/.local/share/Trash` in an intelligent way.

*Intelligent* means: When a specific threshold value (complete size of Trash, age of file or delete-timestamp, count of files, whatever-you-wish) is reached some files (e.g. the most oldest, or where the delete-timestamp is longest ago) will be deleted.

It is important that this feauter need to work independend from the gui-filemanager. That means this meachnism have to work no matter which filemanager is used to move files to the Trash.

Does anyone know a soluton like this?

If not I am free for feauter-wishes and name-wishes for a solution like that. ;)